# How can one tell if a function is defined in a window that has been closed or reloaded?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I have a chrome extension where extension tabs subscribe to events emitted by the background page. The background page's eventing module therefore holds references to handler functions defined in extension tabs.

Extension tabs may be closed, resulting in handlers that still (mostly) work but are no longer needed. A similar situation occurs when an extension tab is reloaded since that reinitializes its `window` object, accumulating superfluous references to (new instances of) functions in the window that are being specified as event handlers on page load.

**What I'm looking for is for the background page eventing module to be able to identify references to handlers specified in extension tabs that have been closed or reloaded so that it may expire them accordingly.**

I have toyed with `unload` and `beforeunload` events to give an extension tab the opportunity to unregister its own handlers. This seems like the most desirable approach in theory. Unfortunately, both of these events proved unreliable.

Comment: I'm kind of confused. Are you looking for something to simply check to see if the other windows are still open?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `window.closed` property. If the global context is live, it is `false`. If the tab/frame is no longer live, `window.closed` is `true` (where `window` is a window object, e.g. `.contentWindow` of an iframe, return value of `window.open`, result of `chrome.extension.getViews()`. etc.)

Though it'd probably be better if you prevent the code from running when the window is dead in the first place.

Comment: I had tried that. Unfortunately after the tab is reloaded, `window.closed` still returns false for the previous context.

Comment: @Hans The `window` thing in my answer refers to a Window object. If you literally used `window.closed`, then it would refer to the current window's `closed` property. I meant something like `var win = window.open();win.close(); alert(win.closed);`

Comment: Yea I got that. Say an extension tab when loaded registers its globally-declared function foo() with the bg page. When the extension tab is reloaded, the background page eventing module (my own implementation) now references 2 separate instances of foo(): one for the current global context and one for the context that was replaced by the reload. When the appropriate event is triggered in the bg page, both instances of foo() are called and `window.closed` yields `false` when evaluated within foo() in both cases. Perhaps a Chrome bug?

Comment: @Hans Could you show some sample code that illustrates your bug? When a page is correctly disposed, `window` will be `undefined`. E.g. try the following in the console: `w = window.open();` (switch to new tab) `function foo(){return window;}` (close tab and switch back to original tab) `w.foo() === undefined;` // true.

Comment: Oh I see. I falsely assumed the observed behavior indicated that a tab reload creates a new `window` object, whereas it just creates a new instance of the handler function in the same global context. These instances accumulate in the bg eventing module each time the tab is reloaded. So it seems I should inspect `document` (not `window.document`!) in the handler to determine whether it's "stale". It looks like `!!document.location` gets me what I need. Do you see any immediate issues with that? Thanks btw for your follow up. Your sample code really helped my understanding.

Comment: @Hans I'd like to see a full snippet before affirmatively answering your question. Apparently you have a reference to a document from another window? If so, try to check for the non-existence of `doument.defaultView` (if the window is not closed yet, `document.defaultView === window /* of that document*/`.

Comment: Sorry, I made some bad assumptions up front and articulated the question poorly, but your feedback led me to a better understanding and what I believe to be a suitable solution. Will edit original post to clarify and submit an answer. To respond to your question, it's not references to documents I end up with. It's references to (handler) functions in another window that are superfluous because either a) the window is closed, or b) the window has been reloaded. In the latter case, different instances of a handler function accumulate for the same window since we subscribe on each page load.

Answer (score 0):

Just check for reloadwin2() throughout your script, probaly in a loop of some kind.

```
function reloadwin2(){
if (otherwindow.closed)
{
return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to feedback from @Rob, I've come up with the following test:

`window && window.document===document`

If this expression evaluates to `false` when called within a handler, then either its tab has been closed (first test) or its tab has been reloaded since the handler was defined (second test).

A handler can return the result of this test to signal to the eventing module to expire it if it's stale.

The second test works because the non-qualified reference to `document` is accessed via closure. It's always going to be equal to `window.document` *at the time the handler was defined*. `window.document`, on the other hand, always returns the current `document` object. When they're the same, then the handler instance is that of the last page load. Of course you don't have to use `document` for this. Any object property of `window` (eg, your own global var) will do.

For the record, extension tabs in my implementation also subscribe to `window.unload` so they can explicitly unregister their own handlers at the appropriate time. This works mostly, but there are some edge cases for which the above approach serves as a suitable fallback.